# How can I create a DDL user in Microsoft Fabric DW?

Tags: sql, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-fabric

How can I create a user which isn't myself that I can use to connect to Fabric DW? Since SQL Authentication is not implemented/turned off for this I need a way to programmatically load data into the warehouse.

Could I possibly solve this using a service principal which I add to Fabric DW?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I create a user which isn't myself that I can use to connect to Fabric DW?

***Microsoft Fabric DW doesn't support SQL Authentication.*** **In Microsoft Fabric, CREATE USER cannot be explicitly executed currently. When GRANT or DENY is executed, the user will be created automatically.**

You can share your Warehouse by choosing **Share** from quick action and add the respective user who should access the data warehouse in fabric.

[image]

By default, the shared recipient is granted "Read" permission, allowing connection to the SQL analytics endpoint (similar to CONNECT permissions in SQL Server). However, to query tables or views or execute functions or stored procedures, the recipient needs explicit access granted using T-SQL [GRANT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-transact-sql?view=fabric&preserve-view=true)  statements.